# Agrupar, contar ciertos valores y sumar cantidades en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo que la siguente tabla en SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE totems_stats (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(3) NULL,
    send_type VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    per VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    cant_im INT NULL,
    fecha_alta DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
);
```

type pueden ser 5: (RRP, DFR, POL, RTR, ERT)

send_type pueden ser 2: (print, email)

per pueden ser 2: (Mensual, Semestral)

cant_im es un numero que puede ser minimo 1

Necesito que me agrupe por `type`
Que me cuente la cantidad de `print` que tiene cada `type`, la cantidad de `email` que tiene cada `type`. Tambien que me sume todos los cant_im de cada type, tanto todos los que tienen `print` como `email

La consulta deberia generar algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me esta costando mucho realizar esta query me podrian dar una mano por que camino debo seguir?. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo, solo necesitas poner condicionales (CASE) dentro de las funciones de agregado. COUNT solo cuenta valores no nulos, así que no ponemos ELSE.

```
SELECT [type],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN send_type = 'print' THEN 1 END) AS count_print,
        COUNT( CASE WHEN send_type = 'email' THEN 1 END) AS count_email,
        SUM( CASE WHEN send_type = 'print' THEN cant_im ELSE 0 END) AS cant_im_print,
        SUM( CASE WHEN send_type = 'email' THEN cant_im ELSE 0 END) AS cant_im_email
FROM totems_stats
GROUP BY [type];
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciona perfecto!!!